# I cannot train my model using transfer learning (VGG16) on my GPU

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to use transfer learning to train my model to detect diseases in rice on images of the plant. I attempted using VGG16, but I could not get it to train with my GPU. I have an NVIDIA GeForce MX150.

Below is the code that I used to fit the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
    # fit the model
    r = model.fit(
        training_set,
        validation_data=test_set,
        epochs=20,
        steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
        validation_steps=len(test_set)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow GPU support requires a few dependencies. Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Then, try `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` - if this is `True`, then your GPU is being used for training.

On a single GPU, you should not need to use `with` to train on GPU. For me to help more, please provide any logs or errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Stanley! 
```tf.test.is_gpu_available()``` returns ```True``` but it is training very slowly (~10 minutes per epoch).

Comment: Then you are running on GPU. Unfortunately, with a small GPU such as the MX150, the speedup will not be huge compared to CPU. It is still possible you are being bottlenecked by CPU if you have a lot of augmentations (check if GPU usage is 100%). Perhaps also try a smaller network such as a ResNet or EfficientNet as VGG16 has a lot more parameters. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, Stanley! You have been a great help

Comment: Hi Stanley, when I checked my Task Manager, my GPU is at 0%. Doesn't that mean that my GPU isn't running?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure, as I use Linux. That does seem to indicate the model is not running on GPU. However, it is also my understanding that if `tf.test.is_gpu_available()` returns True, then it should be running on a GPU. I am not certain, my apologies.